# ES6 classes, with parent in different file, and node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the right way to use a class defined in one file and extend it another, in node.js?

Currently I have:

```
'use strict'

class BasePageHandler {

    constructor(app, settings, context) {

    }
}

return module.exports;
```

In the 'child' class file I have:

```
'use strict'

var BasePageHandler = require ('./../BasePageHandler.js');

class FrontpagePageHandler extends BasePageHandler {
    constructor(app, settings, context) {
         super(app, settings, context);
         this.settings = settings;
         this.context = context;
    }
}
```

This fails with the following error:

```
TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a function or null
```

Note, if I have the BasePageHandler in the same file then it works, so it is really when the class is in another file I have an issue.

Currently using node 4.4.0.

Comment: You may want to use [ES6 native modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) with the [Common JS transform plugin for Babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs), instead `module.exports`. That way, your code will stay future-ready for when Node implements modules natively.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to correctly export your class in`BasePageHandler.js` file:

```
module.exports = BasePageHandler;
```

Comment: Indeed. I missed the obvious :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can also just put it on 1 line: `module.exports = class BasePageHandler {` that way if you rename the class, it's 1 less place to change it later.

Comment: Event after doing this, I'm still having the same issue? I'm using the `harmony_destructuring` flag!

Comment: I had an issue similar where I was trying to return the class by making module.exports into a function. It worked but not as expected. By simply defining module.exports to be the class, everything worked as expected.

Comment: I did it too, but it does not work for me, any other solution please @madox2

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer is technically fine, but really if you're using ES6 then you should go all in and use [ES6 export/import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */

class BasePageHandler {
    constructor(app, settings, context) {
    }
}

export default BasePageHandler;
```

and then:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */

import BasePageHandler from './../BasePageHandler.js';

class FrontpagePageHandler extends BasePageHandler {
    constructor(app, settings, context) {
         super(app, settings, context);
         this.settings = settings;
         this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, there's no need 'use strict' in ES6 - it's enforced by default.